# "over the period shown" or "over the shown period"?

Tags: writing, ielts

I saw people using "over the period shown"  instead of "over the shown period". Could someone explain me why ?
Thanks

Comment: Please never say "explain me": that verb cannot take an indirect object the way *tell* can. You must use "explain (something) to someone" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word shown can be used before and after the described noun; this is true of all adjectives that are derived from the perfect conjugation of verbs:

The played song reminded me of home.

The song played reminded me of home.

Answer (score 1):

Some adjectives, adverbs, and participles can be used after nouns in a similar way to relative clauses. **It's the only solution** (*which is*) **possible**.